# Apply a conjunction of constraints to a parameter pack

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++-concepts, c++20

Given a simple variadoc template

```
template<typename... T>
class A {};
```

and two or more concepts `C1` and `C2` like

```
template<typename T>
concept bool C1() { ... };
```

how can I apply a conjunction of `C1`and `C2` on all elements of the parameter pack of `A` like:

```
template<typename... T>
requires C1<T>... || C2<T>...     // nok
class A {};
```

The above doesn't compile. I'm looking for a way to specify this without writing a new concept like `C1orC2`.

Comment: I think you just got you fold expression syntax wrong. It's `(C1<T> || ...) || (C2<T> || ...)`. And if you mean the parameter pack should be applied as a whole `C1<T...> || C2<T...>`

Comment: I made a mistake in formulating the concept, edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest fold expressions for this:

```
template<typename... T>
requires ((C1<T> || C2<T>) || ...)
class A {};
```

Also, the actual concept should be of the form:

```
template<typename T>
concept C1 = requires(T arg) {
    // something
};
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I made a mistake in formulating the concept (it is NOT variadic), please see above.

Comment: @wimalopaan Ok, I fixed it.Be careful next time :)

Comment: Sorry one more time. Works. But if you you use functional concepts like me be sure to include `()` in the call of the constraints in the fold expression.

Comment: @wimalopaan Don't be. I rather use the soon-to-be official [Concept TS](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) though :)

Comment: or `((C1<T> || C2<T>) || ...)` no?

Comment: @Yakk Yes of course :) IMO it looks a bit weird to abuse fold expressions like that